# Does a GPL Bison grammar infect my application?

Tags: open-source, gpl, parsing

I am thinking about using a GPL Bison grammar for my own compiler.

Will the grammar "infect" my parser such that it needs to be open source?

The grammar - in terms of - the input of bison is GPL.

Comment: Please clarify.  Do you mean the grammar (i.e. the input to Bison) is GPL or are you concerned about using Bison because it it GPL?

Comment: @Craig the output of a program is typically not under the license of the program that generated it.  However, `bison` includes a sizeable amount of code that is under the GPL in its output, which would mean that anything that used it would be under the GPL too... unless there was an exception to be able to use bison for non-gpl programs.

Comment: @MichaelT Yes but if he means that the grammar itself is covered by the GPL (e.g. it was taken from a GPL program) then the GPL of the grammar will probably make his program a derived work. Clarification of the actual question is needed.

Comment: Bison generates parsers for LALR(1) languages.  If your language is *inherently* LALR(1), there are probably some fairly serious crocks in it that make it difficult to USE as well as difficult to parse.  You will probably get a lot more lift from simplifying your language enough that you can write a straightforward recursive descent parser (RDP) for it.  RDPs tend to be significantly easier to write and maintain than LALR(1) grammars and parsing actions.

Comment: for clarification: i meant the input of bison

Answer (score 7):

While Bison itself is licensed under the GPL, a **parser created by Bison** is not automatically covered by the GPL, at least not with recent versions of Bison:

> Conditions for Using Bison
>
> The distribution terms for Bison-generated parsers permit using the
>   parsers in nonfree programs. Before Bison version 2.2, these extra
>   permissions applied only when Bison was generating LALR(1) parsers in
>   C. And before Bison version 1.24, Bison-generated parsers could be
>   used only in programs that were free software.

*Source: http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Conditions*

However, a **parser created from a GPL-licensed grammar** is most likely covered by the GPL as well, because it is a "work based on" the grammar (it is an automatic conversion, like compiling a program).

Of course, as in all legal matters, there is no definitive answer, and even lawyers and judges may disagree, but I believe this is the general consensus.

Comment: I don't think he's asking about the license of Bison, he's asking about the license of the grammar.

Comment: The actual license exception that allows you to use a Bison-generated parser in non-free projects can be found here: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bison.git/tree/src/parse-gram.h

Comment: @JörgWMittag: As Bison is GPL software and parts of Bison make it into the generated grammar, the license of Bison is very relevant.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau: Yes, but that is irrelevant to the question. The OP wasn't asking whether Bison being GPL makes his parser a derived work of Bison, he was asking whether the grammar being GPL makes his parser a derived work of the grammar.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: I see where the confusion comes from. This needs clarification from the OP

Comment: I expanded my answer to address the case of GPL-licensed grammar.